# Javascript matrix assignment behaves differently in case of fill than in case of creating matrix using loop. Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

While creating a matrix in Javascript (array of arrays) I used two different ways -

**1. Using Array.fill**

```js
// Create a matrix using .fill
var aMatrix = new Array(5).fill(new Array(5));
aMatrix[0][0] = 'X';
// 'X' gets copied to all the 0th elements of each row
console.log(aMatrix);


function visualize(aArray, title) {
  // Utility method to visualize value
  var oTable = document.createElement("table");
  var oTh = document.createElement("th");
  oTh.setAttribute('colspan', 5);
  oTh.innerHTML = "<td>" + title + "</td>";
  oTable.appendChild(oTh);
  for (var iIndex = 0; iIndex < 5; iIndex++) {
    var oRow = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var jIndex = 0; jIndex < 5; jIndex++) {
      var oColumn = document.createElement("td");
      oColumn.innerHTML = aArray[iIndex][jIndex] ? aArray[iIndex][jIndex] : '';
      oRow.appendChild(oColumn);
    }
    oTable.appendChild(oRow);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(oTable);
}

visualize(aMatrix, "Matrix created Using Fill");
```

```css
body{
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
}

table th {
  text-align: center;
}


table td{
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px; 
  background: #3399FF;
  text-align: center;
}

table td:empty{
  background: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<center><h3>
While calling aMatrix[0]0] = 'X';
</h3>
</center>
```

**2. Using good old loop**

```js
// Create a matrix using loop
var bMatrix = new Array(5);
for (var iRow = 0; iRow < 5; iRow++) {
  bMatrix[iRow] = new Array(5);
}

bMatrix[0][0] = 'X';


function visualize(aArray, title) {
  // Utility method to visualize value
  var oTable = document.createElement("table");
  var oTh = document.createElement("th");
  oTh.setAttribute('colspan', 5);
  oTh.innerHTML = "<td>" + title + "</td>";
  oTable.appendChild(oTh);
  for (var iIndex = 0; iIndex < 5; iIndex++) {
    var oRow = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var jIndex = 0; jIndex < 5; jIndex++) {
      var oColumn = document.createElement("td");
      oColumn.innerHTML = aArray[iIndex][jIndex] ? aArray[iIndex][jIndex] : '';
      oRow.appendChild(oColumn);
    }
    oTable.appendChild(oRow);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(oTable);
}

visualize(bMatrix, "Matrix created Using Loop");
```

```css
body{
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
}

table th {
  text-align: center;
}


table td{
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px; 
  background: #3399FF;
  text-align: center;
}

table td:empty{
  background: #efefef;
}
```

```html
<center><h3>
While calling aMatrix[0]0] = 'X';
</h3>
</center>
```

On calling matrix[0][0] = 'X' , my expectation was that only 1st element of 1st row would be set to 'X'.

However, in first case, assigning a value to aMatrix[0][0] ends up assigning it to the entire 1st column of all rows.

Why does this happen ?

Comment: Cleaner JS Fiddle - 
https://jsfiddle.net/vaibhavar/bmjosjp7/15/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in first case, assigning a value to aMatrix[0][0] ends up assigning it to the entire 1st column of all rows.

Because when you `.fill`, if the argument to `.fill` is an object, and objects don't get copied. (`aMatrix[0] === aMatrix[1]` - they both reference the same memory address.)

```js
const arr = new Array(5).fill({});
console.log(arr[1] === arr[2]);
```

But if you do this:

```
for (var iRow = 0; iRow < 5; iRow++) {
  bMatrix[iRow] = new Array(5);
}
```

then the `new Array(5)` runs 5 times, creating a new array each time.

Comment: ah, that explains it well.
Thank you!